# jquery mousewheel horizontal scrolling on trackpad. avoid conflicts between deltaX and deltaY

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I use the jquery mousewheel plugin for a horizontal scrolling website. Vertical mousewheel movement is translated to horizontal scrolling. 
When a trackpad is used, conflicts appear because sometimes it is not clear whether to scroll right or left. (for example if you move top right on the trackpad)

How can I make this work smoothly like on this page: http://www.yangrutherford.com/en/work

```
$('#scroll').on('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 1.5);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a mouse with a vertical-only wheel, but I would assume that whichever delta component is larger shows the intent of the user. This works for me unless the movement is very slow or the user moves at 45 degrees in any direction:

```
$('#scroll').on('mousewheel',function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //use whichever component (deltaX or deltaY) that has the largest absolute value
    // deltaX needs negated to have natural scroll motion
    var singleDelta = (Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY)) ? (-1 * deltaX) : deltaY;

    this.scrollLeft-= (singleDelta * 1.5);
});
```